# Lightbox 2 in internet explorer 9

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I have a problem with lightbox 2.
For some reason it doesn't work on my website when I open it in internet explorer 9.
When you click on a picture the overlay is greyish and you can't close or navigate.
The website is online so you can see the problem: [one of my test albums](http://tintopix.com/Profile.aspx?Mode=ViewAlbum&User=fotokader&AlbumName=tests).
The reason it has to work on ie9 is because we need to present it at school, and the only browser there is ie9, so if it doesn't work people wouldn't be able to test it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: by the looks of it you have some missing `)`. please check your console for errors and fix them first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have IE 8 So I can not replicate your problem but when i open your site i found 2 error.

1). bracket is not properly closed. here are the corrected code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
     //ipad and iphone fix
     if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
        $(".drop li ul").click(function(){
      });
     }
    }); // added
```

2).  syntax error

```
Error: SyntaxError: function statement requires a name
Source File: http://tintopix.com/js/lightbox.js
Line: 351, Column: 25
Source Code:
updateImageList: function() {
```

I think second error of light box is not working due to first error so please correct first error then check. i think it will work.